# How to pass chunk length from upload method to streaming content?

Tags: python, flask, ftputil

In my Flask project I use [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/) library. In one of the application sections I use content streaming as described in [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/):

```
@app.route('/section')
def section():
    def generate():
        ftp.upload(source, target, "b", callback)
        yield 'completed'
    return Response(generate())
```

Function `generate` from the example makes file uploading to FTP server as described in [ftputil documentation](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation#callback-function).

Callback function [`callback(chunk)`] used in `upload` method executes for each uploaded file chunk.

Is there any posibility to output `len(chunk)` from the callback to the stream? Any dirty hacks are also very much welcome.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that ftp.upload() runs synchronously, which would make sense. I haven't tested the code below so it's probably riddled with bugs but the idea should work.

```
import threading, Queue

@app.route('/section')
def section():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    def callback(chunk):
        q.put(len(chunk))
    t = threading.Thread(target=lambda: ftp.upload(source, target, "b", callback) or q.put(None))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    def generate():
        while 1:
            l = q.get()
            if l is None:
                return
            yield unicode(l) + '\n'
    return Response(generate())
```

Comment: That's a nice issue. I was trying to make something with threads and queues but it failed to work. I will check it. Thank you!